# Get the Multi-column filter condition data from MUI datagrid table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, mui-datatable

I want to get the filtered data from MUI DataGrid Table and want to send it to backend
Please suggest how should I save the filter condition data .

```
export default function MultiFilteringGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 200,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = React.useState({
    items: [
      { id: 1, columnField: 'commodity', operatorValue: 'contains', value: 'rice' },
      { id: 2, columnField: 'quantity', operatorValue: '>=', value: '20000' },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGridPro
        {...data}
        filterModel={filterModel}
        onFilterModelChange={(model) => setFilterModel(model)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]